# Disable Info Logs in Hive

Tags: java, hadoop, logging, hive, log4j

I have installed Hive (version 3.1.2) with hadoop (version 3.2.1)as a single node cluster. Whenever I login into hive shell and execute a basic query of show databases, I get a bunch of INFO logs that I want to hide.

```
2021-05-26T16:12:44,244 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf - Using the default value passed in for log id: f7369a83-e107-48ed-91cc-569ba580c7c8
2021-05-26T16:12:44,244 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState - Updating thread name to f7369a83-e107-48ed-91cc-569ba580c7c8 main
OK
default
development
retail_ods
retail_stage
Time taken: 0.026 seconds, Fetched: 4 row(s)
2021-05-26T16:12:44,285 INFO [f7369a83-e107-48ed-91cc-569ba580c7c8 main] org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf - Using the default value passed in for log id: f7369a83-e107-48ed-91cc-569ba580c7c8
2021-05-26T16:12:44,285 INFO [f7369a83-e107-48ed-91cc-569ba580c7c8 main] org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState - Resetting thread name to  main
```

This is my hive-log4j2.properties file. I have changed the log levels to ERROR but it doesn't work.

```
hive.root.logger=ERROR,DRFA
hive.log.dir=${java.io.tmpdir}/${user.name}
hive.log.file=hive.log

log4j.rootLogger=${hive.root.logger}, EventCounter

log4j.threshold=${hive.log.threshold}

log4j.appender.DRFA=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender

log4j.appender.DRFA.File=${hive.log.dir}/${hive.log.file}

log4j.appender.DRFA.DatePattern=.yyyy-MM-dd

log4j.appender.DRFA.MaxBackupIndex= 10
log4j.appender.DRFA.MaxFileSize = 100MB
log4j.appender.DRFA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

log4j.appender.DRFA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %-5p [%t]: %c{2} (%F:%M(%L)) - %m%n

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.err
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} [%t]: %p %c{2}: %m%n
log4j.appender.console.encoding=UTF-8

log4j.appender.EventCounter=org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HiveEventCounter

log4j.category.DataNucleus=ERROR,DRFA
log4j.category.Datastore=ERROR,DRFA
log4j.category.Datastore.Schema=ERROR,DRFA
log4j.category.JPOX.Datastore=ERROR,DRFA
log4j.category.JPOX.Plugin=ERROR,DRFA
log4j.category.JPOX.MetaData=ERROR,DRFA
log4j.category.JPOX.Query=ERROR,DRFA
log4j.category.JPOX.General=ERROR,DRFA
log4j.category.JPOX.Enhancer=ERROR,DRFA


log4j.logger.org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn=WARN,DRFA
log4j.logger.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO=WARN,DRFA
```

Please let me know how can I hide all these INFO logs in hive shell.

Comment: can you try `hive -S` ?

Comment: @KoushikRoy Didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

Mine works after adding this property in **hive-site.xml** (inside **/conf** directory of installation folder) :

```
<property>
    <name>hive.async.log.enabled</name>
    <value>false</value> 
</property>
```